# Extjs how to create a new instance of the store without modifying the old one

Tags: extjs, treestore

I have a store that I call like this:

`var store = Ext.getStore('mysotreid');`

`mystoreid` matches with `mycomponent.mystore`.

then I create a new instance of the store like this:

```
var newStore = Ext.create('mycomponent.mystore', {
            autoDestroy: true
        });
```

then I call the load for newStore like this:

```
newStore.load({
            callback: function(items) {
              ...
            }
);
```

The thing is that if I call `var store = Ext.getStore('mysotreid')` it is not the oldone store, but `newStore`. How can I load `newStore` without modifying the old store?

Comment: Did you create 2 times a store using `Ext.create` ? Does each of them have the same `storeId` parameters ?

Comment: yes, the storeid is the same... would that be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one `Ext.create('Ext.data.Store')` with same `storeId` override reference. After that `Ext.getStore('storeIdentifier');` has reference to last.

Look on fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2sas